# Make a flat object nested in js

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to transform my object into nested object in order to be able to render inputs recursively in react (if input has sub input render below this inputs) Sometimes inputs are in wrong order so I have to transform object like this

```js
const start = {
  asdf: {
    id: "asdf",
    question: "How old are you?",
    type: "text"
  },
  "asdf/zxcv": {
    id: "asdf/zxcv",
    expect: 18,
    question: "Are you male?",
    type: "text"
  },
  "asdf/zxcv/yuio": {
    id: "asdf/zxcv/yuio",
    expect: "yes",
    question: "Do you like videogames?",
    type: "text"
  },
  "asdf/dfgh": {
    id: "asdf/dfgh",
    expect: 21,
    question: "Where do you live?",
    type: "text"
  },
  "asdf/dfgh/fghj": {
    id: "asdf/dfgh/fghj",
    expect: "Boston",
    question: "What's the weather?",
    type: "text"
  },
  qwer: {
    id: "qwer",
    question: "What is your name?",
    type: "text"
  },
  "qwer/asdf": {
    id: "qwer/asdf",
    expect: "David",
    question: "What is your surname",
    type: "text"
  }
};
```

into something like this

```js
const result = {
  asdf: {
    id: "asdf",
    question: "How old are you?",
    type: "text",
    subs: [
      {
        id: "asdf/zxcv",
        expect: 18,
        question: "Are you male?",
        type: "text",
        subs: [
          {
            id: "asdf/zxcv/yuio",
            expect: "yes",
            question: "Do you like videogames?",
            type: "text"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "asdf/dfgh",
        expect: 21,
        question: "Where do you live?",
        type: "text",
        subs: [
          {
            id: "asdf/dfgh/fghj",
            expect: "Boston",
            question: "What's the weather?",
            type: "text"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  qwer: {
    id: "qwer",
    question: "What is your name?",
    type: "text",
    subs: [
      {
        id: "qwer/asdf",
        expect: "David",
        question: "What is your surname",
        type: "text"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I can create the first level of objects but I don't know how to add dynamically object to subs if needed

This is my try. It doesn't work.

```js
const createObjToRender = object => {
  Object.values(object)
    .filter(o => o)
    .reduce((obj, el) => {
      const idHistory = el.id.split("/");

      if (idHistory.length > 1) {
        let elToAddSubInput = obj;

        for (let i = 0; i <= idHistory.length; i++) {
          i === 0 && (elToAddSubInput = elToAddSubInput[idHistory[i]]);
          i > 0 && (elToAddSubInput = elToAddSubInput.subs[idHistory[i]]);
        }

        elToAddSubInput.subs[idHistory.join("/")] = el;
      }

      if (idHistory.length === 1) {
        const id = idHistory[0];
        const { question, type } = el;
        if (!obj[id]) {
          obj[id] = {
            id,
            question,
            type,
            subs: {}
          };
        }
      }
    }, {});
};
```

Comment: is your data sorted? please add your try.

Comment: it's not sorted I added my try but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested hashtable for building the tree fast:

```js
const start = {
  asdf: {
    id: "asdf",
    question: "How old are you?",
    type: "text"
  },
  "asdf/zxcv": {
    id: "asdf/zxcv",
    expect: 18,
    question: "Are you male?",
    type: "text"
  },
  "asdf/zxcv/yuio": {
    id: "asdf/zxcv/yuio",
    expect: "yes",
    question: "Do you like videogames?",
    type: "text"
  },
  "asdf/dfgh": {
    id: "asdf/dfgh",
    expect: 21,
    question: "Where do you live?",
    type: "text"
  },
  "asdf/dfgh/fghj": {
    id: "asdf/dfgh/fghj",
    expect: "Boston",
    question: "What's the weather?",
    type: "text"
  },
  qwer: {
    id: "qwer",
    question: "What is your name?",
    type: "text"
  },
  "qwer/asdf": {
    id: "qwer/asdf",
    expect: "David",
    question: "What is your surname",
    type: "text"
  }
};

// We use a symbol to allow fast lookups while still having a resulting array without it
const lookup = Symbol();
const root = { [lookup]: {}, sub: [] };

// As the ids are part of the values itself, we can ignore the objects keys and directly iterate the values
for(const el of Object.values(start)) {
  // Now we traverse down the nested lookup tree 
  let parent = root;
  for(const part of el.id.split("/")) {
    // If a certain path doesnt exist yet, set it up
    if(!parent[lookup][part]) 
      parent.sub.push(parent[lookup][part] = { [lookup]: {}, sub: [] });
    // Dive deeper
    parent = parent[lookup][part];
  }
  // We reached the node were the data belongs, so just assign it here:
  Object.assign(parent, el);
}

// you could also get it as an array with root.sub
console.log(root[lookup]);
```